# Coupled method PHP OO

Tags: php

I'm picking up a bit to create a method for database as shown in the example below:

```
$db = new Query();

$db->select('field')
   ->from('table')
   ->where('condition')
   ->etc. etc.
```

Ie a method with another to return a complete sql (SELECT FROM table WHERE condition fields etc etc).

My question is: How to create a class?

Grateful.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: My question is: How to create a class?

Comment: `class Query{}` and simply return `$this` at the end of every method that you want to chain.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) explains it better. This website isn't for learning the basics to a language fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you just return `$this` at the end of each method you want to be chain-able.

Using your sample API, the implementation would look something like this:

```
<?php

class Query {

    public function select($arg) {
        // do stuff
        return $this;
    }

    public function from($arg) {
        // do stuff
        return $this;
    }

    public function where($arg) {
        // do stuff
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alexander O'Mara.